# osmconvert bounding box not working

Tags: openstreetmap, osmconvert

I am trying to get specific city extracts from a european.osm.pbf file using osmosis or osmconvert and am instead outputting files with practically no relation to the boundng polygon at all.

The boundary is generated with [link](https://polygons.openstreetmap.fr/) and then the command is

```
osmconvert europe-latest.osm.pbf -B=polygons/berlin.poly --complete-ways -o=berlin-osmconvert.osm.pbf
```

berlin.poly:

```
polygon
1
    13.084  52.419
    13.086  52.423
    13.095  52.426
    13.095  52.428
    13.098  52.429
    13.105  52.429
    13.108  52.431
    13.108  52.434
    13.116  52.44
    13.105  52.449
    13.105  52.452
    13.108  52.455
    13.107  52.468
    13.114  52.475
    13.114  52.479
    13.119  52.482
    13.125  52.482
    13.147  52.5
    13.16   52.508
    13.149  52.513
    13.145  52.513
    13.142  52.516
    13.123  52.513
    13.116  52.513
    13.113  52.516
    13.115  52.531
    13.121  52.541
    13.121  52.545
    13.126  52.557
    13.129  52.56
    13.133  52.56
    13.136  52.557
    13.143  52.556
    13.142  52.563
    13.15   52.575
    13.148  52.579
    13.14   52.576
    13.131  52.576
    13.128  52.579
    13.126  52.579
    13.124  52.582
    13.124  52.586
    13.127  52.591
    13.134  52.591
    13.137  52.593
    13.145  52.594
    13.156  52.602
    13.163  52.603
    13.175  52.599
    13.185  52.598
    13.192  52.594
    13.202  52.593
    13.205  52.591
    13.212  52.592
    13.204  52.597
    13.198  52.603
    13.198  52.609
    13.204  52.612
    13.215  52.624
    13.217  52.631
    13.261  52.632
    13.261  52.635
    13.258  52.638
    13.258  52.642
    13.261  52.645
    13.265  52.644
    13.28   52.645
    13.28   52.649
    13.278  52.651
    13.278  52.658
    13.279  52.663
    13.282  52.665
    13.294  52.663
    13.308  52.664
    13.311  52.661
    13.313  52.661
    13.314  52.655
    13.307  52.652
    13.313  52.646
    13.313  52.64
    13.311  52.636
    13.314  52.632
    13.328  52.63
    13.336  52.627
    13.358  52.627
    13.361  52.629
    13.372  52.631
    13.372  52.634
    13.376  52.638
    13.382  52.641
    13.386  52.641
    13.388  52.647
    13.394  52.652
    13.4    52.652
    13.409  52.647
    13.415  52.647
    13.424  52.64
    13.428  52.642
    13.429  52.641
    13.43   52.646
    13.432  52.648
    13.437  52.649
    13.439  52.653
    13.453  52.654
    13.455  52.652
    13.46   52.652
    13.462  52.654
    13.448  52.659
    13.447  52.665
    13.458  52.673
    13.465  52.672
    13.474  52.679
    13.479  52.68
    13.483  52.678
    13.484  52.673
    13.487  52.675
    13.492  52.673
    13.49   52.661
    13.493  52.658
    13.508  52.653
    13.512  52.65
    13.521  52.651
    13.527  52.647
    13.526  52.637
    13.523  52.633
    13.522  52.628
    13.518  52.625
    13.51   52.623
    13.509  52.617
    13.505  52.615
    13.502  52.609
    13.502  52.607
    13.51   52.596
    13.523  52.597
    13.551  52.591
    13.563  52.585
    13.57   52.579
    13.57   52.577
    13.576  52.578
    13.58   52.575
    13.583  52.575
    13.587  52.57
    13.588  52.561
    13.59   52.56
    13.593  52.552
    13.64   52.546
    13.642  52.54
    13.637  52.535
    13.638  52.534
    13.66   52.533
    13.662  52.529
    13.662  52.524
    13.657  52.52
    13.645  52.516
    13.639  52.512
    13.632  52.504
    13.63   52.497
    13.633  52.496
    13.634  52.492
    13.626  52.484
    13.618  52.479
    13.621  52.474
    13.624  52.478
    13.636  52.48
    13.641  52.483
    13.649  52.483
    13.661  52.478
    13.672  52.477
    13.686  52.469
    13.695  52.468
    13.697  52.472
    13.703  52.472
    13.709  52.468
    13.717  52.467
    13.729  52.455
    13.75   52.453
    13.758  52.45
    13.76   52.448
    13.761  52.442
    13.765  52.44
    13.765  52.436
    13.761  52.432
    13.753  52.433
    13.751  52.434
    13.751  52.436
    13.748  52.436
    13.745  52.43
    13.745  52.424
    13.742  52.422
    13.738  52.422
    13.735  52.419
    13.735  52.416
    13.738  52.413
    13.74   52.413
    13.743  52.409
    13.742  52.404
    13.738  52.403
    13.738  52.4
    13.735  52.397
    13.727  52.396
    13.724  52.394
    13.716  52.395
    13.7    52.387
    13.699  52.386
    13.703  52.383
    13.703  52.38
    13.705  52.378
    13.702  52.371
    13.693  52.363
    13.69   52.364
    13.686  52.363
    13.682  52.366
    13.67   52.361
    13.67   52.356
    13.665  52.351
    13.662  52.35
    13.66   52.346
    13.656  52.343
    13.655  52.337
    13.649  52.334
    13.641  52.336
    13.633  52.343
    13.632  52.346
    13.634  52.351
    13.635  52.363
    13.64   52.367
    13.638  52.369
    13.639  52.373
    13.632  52.372
    13.627  52.377
    13.609  52.37
    13.604  52.37
    13.602  52.372
    13.601  52.379
    13.598  52.382
    13.594  52.382
    13.59   52.389
    13.565  52.384
    13.534  52.385
    13.531  52.389
    13.531  52.394
    13.529  52.393
    13.524  52.396
    13.516  52.398
    13.51   52.396
    13.478  52.392
    13.476  52.394
    13.473  52.404
    13.465  52.417
    13.46   52.417
    13.447  52.412
    13.423  52.407
    13.431  52.39
    13.431  52.383
    13.422  52.372
    13.387  52.374
    13.384  52.378
    13.384  52.384
    13.37   52.384
    13.366  52.388
    13.367  52.391
    13.347  52.4
    13.339  52.406
    13.322  52.4
    13.313  52.395
    13.309  52.396
    13.294  52.411
    13.281  52.403
    13.273  52.4
    13.265  52.4
    13.261  52.402
    13.248  52.401
    13.245  52.406
    13.245  52.413
    13.243  52.417
    13.224  52.417
    13.213  52.413
    13.201  52.412
    13.186  52.408
    13.169  52.402
    13.174  52.401
    13.176  52.397
    13.175  52.393
    13.17   52.39
    13.146  52.391
    13.142  52.393
    13.138  52.391
    13.136  52.384
    13.131  52.383
    13.124  52.386
    13.123  52.393
    13.115  52.399
    13.11   52.4
    13.104  52.406
    13.1    52.407
    13.097  52.405
    13.091  52.407
    13.087  52.41
    13.086  52.413
    13.084  52.419
END
!2
    13.698  52.386
    13.698  52.385
    13.699  52.386
    13.698  52.386
END
!3
    13.167  52.401
    13.169  52.401
    13.169  52.402
    13.167  52.401
END
END
```

This should, in theory, output only the information inside the bounding polygon, but when visualized with qgis, I have a nautical boundary of Italy for some reason. There seems to be little to no relationship with the actual boundary when running the command.

[image]

Here is an example image of the qgis output from the database after loading with osm2pgsql. Berlin is the dark spot to the north.